# Compilation error when declaring derived object as a private member in a class

Tags: c++

My compiler is complaining that my declaration of an object as a private member of a different class (shown below) gives me this error:

> private:
>
> ```
>    ForwardStrategy::ForwardStrategy* forwardStrategy;
>
>    ForwardToStrategy::ForwardToStrategy* forwardToStrategy;
> ```

/home/ics45c/projects/p4/src/Person.hpp:45:19: error: qualified reference to 'ForwardStrategy' is a constructor
      name rather than a type wherever a constructor can be declared
        ForwardStrategy::ForwardStrategy* forwardStrategy;
                         ^
/home/ics45c/projects/p4/src/Person.hpp:47:21: error: qualified reference to 'ForwardToStrategy' is a constructor
      name rather than a type wherever a constructor can be declared
        ForwardToStrategy::ForwardToStrategy* forwardToStrategy;
                           ^

2 errors generated.

So it looks like the compiler believes I'm referring to the constructor rather than the type, but I'm not sure how to correct the issue...

Sorry about the awful formatting... I'm not really sure how to do this correctly, but thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it work if you just write `ForwardStrategy* forwardStrategy;` instead of `ForwardStrategy::ForwardStrategy* forwardStrategy;` because I think that the last one refers to members of the class not the class itself (as a new defined type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to :

```
private:

ForwardStrategy* forwardStrategy;

ForwardToStrategy* forwardToStrategy;
```

because the way it's written in your question means you are trying to access a member (which is the constructor function) of this class not defining an instance of it.

Comment: I guess I should have added a little more information, my bad...

The strategies are in their own header file, and I include it at the top of my file

Comment: @user3029740, headers are not the same things as namespaces nor do they implicitly add a namespace. Have you tried what T-D suggested? What worked? What didn't work?

Comment: I resolved the issue. Apparently I had a problem with circular inclusions because I forgot to remove the #include from one of my headers. Thanks for the help though!